# How to generate number of threads(Users) randomly in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

[image]I have tried to generate random thread in this way but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [__Random function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random):

```
${__Random(1,10000000)}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to generate random numbers in Jmeter

- Working with epoch,
- Working with CSV files,
- Working with Random Variable Sampler,

  for more details you can take a look from [Here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/three-ways-to-generate-random-variables-in-jmeter) may be it will help you.